# Pathauto patterns produce segment duplicates

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have set up a pathauto pattern for a wiki-section that looks like this:

```
wiki/[node:menu-link:parent:url:alias]/[node:menu-link:title]
```

I want it to produce links such as `wiki/page` and `wiki/page/subpage` and it works fine for first level links, but for sublinks it duplicates the first segment and produces links such as `wiki/wiki/page/subpage`.

What is the correct pattern I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Use just `[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link:title]` and make sure that you set the root node's URL alias manually as 'wiki'.

Comment: The token you provided doesn't work for me. Maybe we're on different versions. I ended up using [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link] and it works perfectly under Drupal 7.14, Pathauto 7.x-1.1, and Token 7.x-1.1. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, in the latest version [node:menu-link:parent:url:alias] has been changed to use [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]. I'll update my answer.